# How to calculate best path between 2 points from a DEM in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, dem, distance, shortest-path

I'm analyzing the roads and paths of a region by calculating how effective the communication is in the region.

First I calculated the shortest paths between the points using the actual road map.

Now I want to generate a new vector layer by calculating the best paths between the same points in the region from a digital elevation model, using parameters such as shortest distance, lower slope, etc..  The objective is to create artificial paths and compare them with the existing road net.

Comment: What do mean by communication?
As a dem is a raster it would be possible to see it as a cost surface. Cost surfaces and pathes in raster well supported in GIS. At least in grass you will find methods to this.

Comment: Hi Andreas. By "comunications" I mean how effective are actual roads in terms of distance or slope. I'm trying to compare actual roads with some hipothetical roman roads in a region of Catalonia. I guess a model of how they could be "ideal" paths between human settlements in thoose terms could be an interesting factor to add to the comparation.

Comment: Bad news is I'm not familiar with grass. I hoped I could do it by qgis..